# rails has_many through for multiple models - no method for nil:class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have model for properties, residents and people(people outside city so have to be not residents) and then I have owner join table where I set if property belongs to resident, or person

here are my models

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :residents, through: :owners
    has_many :people, through: :owners
    belongs_to :ptype
end

class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :properties, through: :owners
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :properties, through: :owners
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :resident
    belongs_to :property
    belongs_to :person
end
```

I want to have view where I show the relation so if owner.resident show properties or if owner.person show properties

```
 <% if @owner.resident %>
  <ol><% @residents.properties.each do |property| %>
            <li><%= property.ptype.name %> , <%= property.address %></li>
          <% end %> 
</ol>
<% end %>

<% if @owner.person %>
<ol><% @people.properties.each do |property| %>
            <li><%= property.ptype.name %> , <%= property.address %></li>
            <% end %> 
</ol><% end %>
```

when I want to show relation where owner is a resident, I got error no method properties for nil:class for @people and when I want to show relation where owner is a person I got oposite, error no method properties for nil:class for @residents

I understand that it is because it returns no record, but thats why I put there that if

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I use default controllers generated by rails

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_person, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @person.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to people_url, notice: 'Person was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private

    def set_person
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end

    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :email, :tel)
    end
end

class ResidentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_resident, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @residents = Resident.all
  end

  def show
    @residents = Resident.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @resident = Resident.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @resident = Resident.new(resident_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @resident.save
        format.html { redirect_to @resident, notice: 'Záznam bol úspešne vytvorený.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @resident }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @resident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @resident.update(resident_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @resident, notice: 'Záznam bol úspešne upravený.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @resident }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @resident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @resident.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to residents_url, notice: 'Záznam bol úspešne zmazaný.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private

    def set_resident
      @resident = Resident.find(params[:id])
    end
    def resident_params
      params.require(:resident).permit(:name, :birthdate, :birthId, :address, :email, :tel)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show the controller code where you're setting the instance variables `@residents` and `@people`

Comment: added controller code
I use standard generated controller, I thought it is enough as has_many through worked without people model

Answer (score 1):

ok I did it all wrong from begining
this is a solution

```
<% if @owner.resident.present? %>
  <ol><% @owner.resident.properties.each do |property| %>
            <li><%= property.ptype.name %> , <%= property.address %></li>
          <% end %> 
</ol>
<% end %>
<% if @owner.person.present? %>
<ol><% @owner.person.properties.each do |property| %>
            <li><%= property.ptype.name %> , <%= property.address %></li>
          <% end %> 
</ol>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `@owner.person` and `@owner.resident` will return proxy objects until something is done with them - try `@owner.person.present?` and `@owner.resident.present?`

Comment: same error, I already tried unless @owner.person.nil? and was the same error

Comment: Then it sounds like your @owner probably links to both a person and a resident

Comment: <td><%= owner.resident.name if owner.resident %></td>
<td><%= owner.person.name if owner.person %></td>

this code works ok in my datatable so I think it can find if owner is resident or person

Comment: Yes but your actions only either load `@people` or `@residents` -- if you have an @wener that has both a person and a resident associated with it, then either people or residents is not going to be setup for display

Comment: nope, that works ok, I just tried to add a resident where person was already attached to property in owner tab and it shows ok

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're doing --  none of your actions load both  residents and people - so if the owner has both a resident and a person one of `@residents` or `@people` is going to be nil and cause an error

Comment: I am trying to show "pair" of owners between property and residents/people
maybe I am doing something wrong from the begining
EDIT: Ok I am stupid, I found a solution